# Mysql GROUP and SUM Optimization

Tags: mysql, performance, group-by, sum, query-optimization

I have 2 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoryId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `parentId` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `barcode` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `code` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_products_product_categories1_idx` (`categoryId`),
  KEY `fk_products_products1_idx` (`parentId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=71521 ;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `inventory` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `depotId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `productId` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `remain` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `remain2` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `updatedDateTime` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_inventory_depots1_idx` (`depotId`),
  KEY `fk_inventory_products1_idx` (`productId`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=89291 ;
```

Please help me to optimize the following query (what index should be added to improve the performance), Query took 0.2578 sec (MySQL is using index  fk_inventory_depots1_idx), when removing AND i.depotId = 3 Query took 0.5484 sec. EXPLAIN query show that Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort

```
SELECT `p`.* , SUM(i.remain) AS `remain` , SUM(i.remain2) AS `remain2`
FROM `products` AS `p`
LEFT JOIN `inventory` AS `i` ON p.id = i.productId
WHERE remain != 0 AND i.depotId = 3
GROUP BY `p`.`id`
ORDER BY `p`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 50
```

Comment: Create a index on `inventory` table `(productId, remain, depotId)`. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

The `sum()` function used in your statement, would consider all the rows (the `LIMIT` clause would not be valid as its calculated at the last). The could be causing a full table scan as all the values of `remain`, `remain2` are summed up

If you wish to get the `sum()` of the latest `50 rows` use

```
SELECT 
  `p`.* , 
  SUM(i.remain) AS `remain`, 
  SUM(i.remain2) AS `remain2`
FROM
  (
    SELECT `p`.*, 
          i.remain, 
          i.remain2 
    FROM 
      `products` AS `p`
      JOIN `inventory` AS `i` ON p.id = i.productId << This should be a JOIN, as remain and depotId belong to inventory
    WHERE 
      remain != 0 
      AND i.depotId = 3
    GROUP BY 
      `p`.`id`
    ORDER BY 
      `p`.`id` DESC
LIMIT 50  ) as t
```

Comment: I cannot use JOIN here because some products have no remain in inventory table

Comment: But your `WHERE` clauses uses the condition chking from fields that are from inventor (I assume i.remain, i.remain2, remain belong to inventor table

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks ok, however, you have it as a LEFT-JOIN, but by using WHERE remain !=0 and i.DepotID = 3 forces it into an INNER-JOIN.  If you really intended for only entries that HAD non-zero remaining quantities, then you are ok.  But, if you want inventory products regardless, you would have to adjust your query to

```
SELECT 
      `p`.* , 
      SUM(i.remain) AS `remain` , 
      SUM(i.remain2) AS `remain2`
   FROM `
      products` AS `p`
         LEFT JOIN `inventory` AS `i` 
            ON p.id = i.productId
           AND remain != 0 
           AND i.depotId = 3
   GROUP BY 
      `p`.`id`
   ORDER BY 
      `p`.`id` DESC
   LIMIT 50
```

Notice the subtle difference in the "ON" join condition.  This allows all products -- regardless of a matching inventory record.  Now, that said, you are now getting from ALL inventory, not just those of your "DepotID = 3" criteria.

To help your indexing, the only thing I would suggest is a multiple field key.  In this case, you are using most fields in the table for either the JOIN or SUM() purposes.  If the fields are part of the index, it doesn't have to go back to the actual data pages per record.  Small waste, but might get your final results improved.

KEY `fk_inventory_multiplefields_idx` ( productid, depotid, remain, remain2),